# node-sass, media queries and cascading

Tags: css, media-queries, node-sass

**Due to my vague understanding of tools I am using I failed to identify the source of the problem. node-sass does not provide media-queries aggregation, but css-mqpacker does, that is where I had to look for the problem resolvation. https://github.com/hail2u/node-css-mqpacker/issues/49.**

What would be your way out of the following situation.

I merge two partial .scss files by `@import`ing them to base file. Each file has media queries, and they provide styles for respective element of a page.

```
  /* contents of index.scss */
  @import "_block.scss", "_block-2.scss";
```

First file introduces two breakpoints, and order of appearance for these breakpoints in sass compiled stylesheet is defined by order in this file.

```
/* contents of _block.scss */
.block {
  @media (max-width: 500px) {...}
  @media (max-width: 450px) {...}
}
```

The `@import` of the second file has the same set of breakpoints plus one for `max-width: 550px`.

```
/* contents of _block-2.scss */
.block-2 {
  @media (max-width: 550px) {...}
  @media (max-width: 500px) {...}
  @media (max-width: 450px) {...}
}
```

Identical breakpoints are aggregated during compilation, but a new one is placed at the end of compiled stylesheet, overriding properties for all breakpoints for particular element, which is not desirable behavior.

```
/* stylesheet compiled by sass */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .block {...}
    .block-2 {...}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .block {...}
    .block-2 {...}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .block-2 {...}
}
```

What would be a right solution?

This example represents a project where I cannot import second file before the first one because it introduces another problems with overriding.
I ended up defining style specifically to order all existing breakpoints, and introducing it early, but it is a hack I do not like at all, so I still in need for elegant solution.

It concerns me whether there is a use for media queries nested in CSS rules if it leads to such implications. In desktop first and mobile first media queries order matters, but I do not have sufficient control of it even in this simple case.

Comment: you kinda have to give more context based on we don't know what classes it affects and what the reason for having to files are?

Comment: If you can't change the order of the files then change the content of the files so that it works properly. Maybe your selectors are too generic so they override each other. In general, you would have a more generic css as the first file, like a global css that styles global components of the site then a more specific css for a page.

Comment: @Dejan.S Classes are not very relevant IMO, and they add some complexity to explanation. Let us assume that the second file contains styles for `.block-2` and media queries only modify background color. There are two files because it is easier for me to put styles for every component to separate file.

Answer (score 0):

```
.block {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .block {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .block {
        background-color: lavender;
    }
}
```

Also see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: why do you have 500px before 450px?

Comment: *I Wrote It According To The Question Provided*

Comment: @Dejan.S The solution is using max-width, why not have 500 before 450?

Comment: *@Huangism ~ I Didn't Get It ? Were You Telling Me ?*

Comment: Please don't use *italics* or other highlights when adding emphasis is not required.

Comment: @Huangism I guess for readability, just check the answer above, imagine a real scenario with a bunch of queries and classes packed in them.

Comment: @MASTER I'm more interested in dealing with the way node-sass organizes code during compilation, not how to do it manualy, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I added your current setup & and a suggested solution.
This is assumed you really need to run the 2 css files in the order you explained. It is also assumed that you want to keep as-is but have the final result working.

Since you might (for some reason) not want to delete the original values in CSS, you will have to set the ones you do not want to use, to transparent. That is background-color original default.

As a second step you need to decide which max-width you really want. When you know that you can secure the system uses that by adding "!important".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

<style>

/* Current setup */
@media (max-width: 500px) {body {background-color: red}}
@media (max-width: 450px) {body {background-color: blue}}
@media (max-width: 550px) {body {background-color: green}}

/* Solution */
@media (max-width: 500px) {body {background-color: transparent}}
@media (max-width: 450px) {body {background-color: yellow !important;}}
@media (max-width: 550px) {body {background-color: transparent}}


</style>

</head>
<body>
  test
</body>
</html>
```